# Accurate Sleep in milliseconds in Java / C

Tags: java, windows-7, java-native-interface, thread-sleep

I am looking for a way to pause a thread for accurate number of milliseconds in Java or C (I can use JNI to access the C method.

So far, I was using the following in java code.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> SLEEPER = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
SLEEPER.poll(msTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This was suggested on one of the threads in this forum and worked great on most of our windows7 machines.

But it is not giving me accrate results on a new set of hardware. So I decided to use JNI to access C. But even this does not pause for accurate amount of milliseconds on new hardwares (Dell and HP on Windows7).

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JniTimer_jniWait(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj , jint waitTime )              {

HANDLE hWaitEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
   if (hWaitEvent) 
    {

    WaitForSingleObject(hWaitEvent,waitTime);
        CloseHandle (hWaitEvent);
    }
    }
```

Does anyone have a reliable option for accurate sleep on thread.
Thanks.

Comment: Sleeping for a set amount of time is almost impossible due to the granularity of system clocks. For example, a clock might only be precise to within 16 ms. So if you sleep for 50 ms, you'll be woken up in 48ms or 64ms, but never exactly 50.

Comment: Also, after a thread has been made runnable due to timer expiration, there may be a delay before it actually runs due to contention with other threads, and cache misses or even page faults getting the thread restarted.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that on a non RT OS.

Not so much due to the resolution of timers, but because the per thread 'time slice' (sometimes referred to as `quantum`), is usually set to a few ms (15 on my antique xp here), and is not something you can just play with.

Comment: Thanks avip. I did some more testing and it turns out that on one of the machines, if the delay is in multiples of 5ms, I get accurate results. On another machine, so far I have not been able to find the magic number.  Now, question is what is this magic number called ? I tried looking up for time splice/quantum details for a processor but did not find any details on this. Is there a different name that refers to this minimum delay time ?

Comment: It's not 'processor', it's OS + CPU architecture. I think you're drifting here to an unstable solution for a problem you didn't even stated. Mayby post a new SO Q with more details like what exactly youre trying to achieve.